# WPF bind data to user control inside another user control dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Binding issue. How to correctly bind data to a user control inside another user control?

So I have a problem, for me a big one. I'm making a schedule program in WPF. 
To narrow it down, I have two classes (Day and Shift) to hold my data (simplified). Day class contains a list of Shift. A regular day can contain a various number of shifts, i.e. one from 9 to 14 and another from 18 to 22.

```
class Shift
{
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
}
class Day 
{
    List<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have two user controls, a "DayControl" and a "ShiftControl":

```
<UserControl x:Class="Spas.DayControl" ...>
   <StackPanel x:Name="MyShifts"... />
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="Spas.ShiftControl" x:Name="uc"...>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb_startTime" Text="{Binding StartTime, ElementName=uc, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</UserControl>
```

In ShiftControl.xaml.cs:

```
public static DependencyProperty StartTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StartTime", typeof(string), typeof(ShiftControl), new PropertyMetadata("09:00", null, CoerceStartTimeValue));
public string StartTime
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(StartTimeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(StartTimeProperty, value); }
}
```

So what I want to do:
In my main code I will populate my Day with a dynamic number of Shifts. That's the easy part.
From there I want my DayControl to dynamically create as many ShiftControls as number of Shifts and add them to my DayControl's stackpanel. I have managed to do that using the DayControl's DataContextChanged.

Main code:

```
public Day MyDay { get; set; }

private void CreateADay()
{
    MyDay = new Day();
    MyDay.Shifts.Add(new Shift1() { StartTime = "09:00" });
    MyDay.Shifts.Add(new Shift1() { StartTime = "14:00" });
    dc1.DataContext = MyDay; // which is my DayControl in MainWindow
}
```

And my DayControl:

```
private void UserControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Day day = e.NewValue as Day;
    foreach (var item in day.Shifts)
    {
        ShiftControl ctrl = new ShiftControl();
        // here I somehow want to bind item.StartTime to ctrl.StartTime
        // This doesn't work:
        // Binding binding = new Binding("ShiftControl.StartTimeProperty");
        // binding.Source = item.StartTime;
        // binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        // ctrl.SetBinding(ShiftControl.StartTimeProperty, binding);

        _shifts.Children.Add(ctrl);
    }
}
```

But in NO WAY I can't bind (twoway) my Shift data to tb_startTime in my ShiftControl. I have been struggeling with this a few days now and I might just be blind. Help anyone? I can put up my entire project somewhere if needed.

Comment: Please edit to make it clear how this question is not helpful only to you, otherwise this question does not belong on this site and should be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind in code behind then:

```
 private void UserControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    Day day = e.NewValue as Day;
    foreach (var item in day.Shifts)
    {
         ShiftControl ctrl = new ShiftControl();
        // here I somehow want to bind item.StartTime to ctrl.StartTime

         Binding myBinding = new Binding("StartTime");
         myBinding.Source = item;
         ctrl.SetBinding(ShiftControl.StartTimeProperty, myBinding);

         _shifts.Children.Add(ctrl);
 }
}
```

Comment: sure.. also make sure your Shift class and Day clas implements INotifyPropertyChanged and you raise property change notifications

Comment: A new problem. On my StartTimeProperty I have a CoerceStartTimeValue function, so if I enter "10" in my textbox it change to "10:00" (among some other validation rules). But it seems like the source updates before the change. So the source data contains "10" instead of "10:00".

Answer (score 0):

Sample Method to achieve your Requriement. You should design it like below. Assign the shift objects as itemsource to "DayControl" usercontrol's itemsPanel. Here I have used Itemspanel with stackpanel as ItemPanleTemplate.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Spas.DayControl" >
    <ItemsControl x:Name="MyShifts" ItemsSource="{Binding ShiftObjects}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:Spas.ShiftControl />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```